# How to load data in Pig from .tsv file?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a .TSV file containing data in HDFS and i am not able to load it into Pig.
The command i am using is "

```
A = load 'file_location' as (name:chararray, age:int, gpa:float);
B = foreach A generate (name, age);
DUMP B;
```

> Error returned : Unable to find operator for alias A

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

A =  load 'path/of/file' using PigStorage('\t') AS (name:chararray,age:int,gpa:float);

B = foreach A generate name, age;

DUMP B;

ps: I don't think there is any fault with your commands.As tab (\t) is default delimiter for pig . I am getting the correct output with your commands .Can you please send me logs or screenshot of your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not specify the delimiter PIG uses default ',' as the delimiter for loading the file.Hence your load statement is failing.You have to explicitly specify the delimiter '\t'.

```
A = LOAD 'file_location' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (name:chararray, age:int, gpa:float);
```

Comment: Default delimiter of pig is '\t'. You can try it by your own.